# How to make the whatsapp icon visible in small screen?

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

I have a nar bar, the left side is navigation items and the right side is a whatsapp icon.

```
<mat-toolbar class="nav">
   <a routerLink="app-aaa" mat-button>aaa</a>
   <a routerLink="app-bbb" mat-button>bbb</a>
   <a routerLink="app-ccc" mat-button>ccc</a>
   <a routerLink="app-ddd" mat-button>ddd</a>
   <a routerLink="app-eee" mat-button>eee</a>
   <a routerLink="app-fff" mat-button>fff</a>
   <a routerLink="app-ggg" mat-button>ggg</a>
   <a routerLink="app-hhh" mat-button>hhh</a>
   <span><a href="https://api.whatsapp.com//send?phone=1234567890">
       <svg viewBox="0 0 32 32" class="whatsapp-ico">
         <path
            d=" M19.11 17.205c-.372 0-1.088 1.39-1.518 1.39a.63.63 0 0 1-.315-.1c-.802-.402-1.504-.817-2.163-1.447-.545-.516-1.146-1.29-1.46-1.963a.426.426 0 0 1-.073-.215c0-.33.99-.945.99-1.49 0-.143-.73-2.09-.832-2.335-.143-.372-.214-.487-.6-.487-.187 0-.36-.043-.53-.043-.302 0-.53.115-.746.315-.688.645-1.032 1.318-1.06 2.264v.114c-.015.99.472 1.977 1.017 2.78 1.23 1.82 2.506 3.41 4.554 4.34.616.287 2.035.888 2.722.888.817 0 2.15-.515 2.478-1.318.13-.33.244-.73.244-1.088 0-.058 0-.144-.03-.215-.1-.172-2.434-1.39-2.678-1.39zm-2.908 7.593c-1.747 0-3.48-.53-4.942-1.49L7.793 24.41l1.132-3.337a8.955 8.955 0 0 1-1.72-5.272c0-4.955 4.04-8.995 8.997-8.995S25.2 10.845 25.2 15.8c0 4.958-4.04 8.998-8.998 8.998zm0-19.798c-5.96 0-10.8 4.842-10.8 10.8 0 1.964.53 3.898 1.546 5.574L5 27.176l5.974-1.92a10.807 10.807 0 0 0 16.03-9.455c0-5.958-4.842-10.8-10.802-10.8z"
     fill-rule="evenodd">
     </path>
   </svg>
  </a></span>
</mat-toolbar>
```

The correspond css likes:

```
 .whatsapp-ico{
    fill: white;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    padding: 3px;
    background-color: #4dc247;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    z-index: 10;
 }

 .whatsapp-ico:hover{
      box-shadow: 2px 2px 11px rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
 }

 .nav {
      background-color: lightgray;
      font-weight: 700;
      font-size: 24px;
      text-decoration: none;
      color: #fff;
  }
 .nav span {
     margin-left: 25%;
 }
```

It works well in desktop. All the items and the icon are in the same row. But if I test it in small screen, say iphone mode. The icon is not visible and some nav items on the right are cut off. How to make it responsive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution by myself. In the `nav` class. I added something like.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    flex-direction: column;
    height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use @media to make your website resposive

you can find some info here https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_intro.asp

i personally make a css file for every different device like

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-device-width: 320px)"href="css/320style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-device-width: 760px)"href="css/760style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-device-width: 900px)"href="css/900style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-device-width: 1200px)"href="css/1200style.css">
```

and you use this or use different width.

its better if you start from a phone view and then go up (you can delete the first 320style and make a normal css so it works for every device even if it is -320px width)

Comment: I would like a specific example for my case.